# How to sort a column from a text file in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, columnsorting

I am a beginner and our activity is about sorting algorithms we need to sort the inputs from the text file according to last name or first name. Does anyone know how to sort a column from a text file?  And also, I don't know how I can merge the other columns so that it will be sorted accordingly with the first name. Thanks for the help! Here's my code:

```
void sortFirst() {
    string sortedFirst;
    string firstname[20];
    
    string key;
    string col1;
    string col2;
    string col3;
    
    ifstream sortByFirst;
    
    cout << "\n\n\tSORTED BY FIRST NAME ================\n\n";

    sortByFirst.open("student-file.txt");

    while(getline(sortByFirst, sortedFirst)) 
    {
        istringstream iss(sortedFirst); 
        iss >> col1 >> col2 >> col3; 
//      cout << "\t" << col2 << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i<1; i++) {
        firstname[i] = col2;
//      cout << "\n" << firstname[i];

    for (int a = 1, b = 0; a < 20; a++) {
        key = firstname[a];
        b = a-1;
        
        while (b >= 0 && firstname[b] > key) {
            firstname[b+1] = firstname[b];
            b--;
        }
        firstname[b+1] = key;
    }
    } 
    }
    
    for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++) {
        cout << "\n\t" << firstname[k];
    }

    sortByFirst.close();
    
}
```

Here is the text file where I need to sort by the first name alphabetically:

| LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lorzano | Jeff | 78.23 |
| Garcia | Zen | 89.56 |
| Villa | Luz | 98.25 |
| Mercado | Cherrie | 92.10 |
| Lopez | Cecile | 74.10 |
| Garcia | LJ | 89.45 |
| Lina | Carol | 97.55 |
| Villegas | Cindy | 78.89 |
| Litan | Irene | 84.52 |
| Austria | Lina | 89.00 |
| Chavez | Cheska | 91.65 |
| DelosReyes | Melody | 70.00 |
| Wong | Chris | 87.00 |
| Maralit | Ian | 75.45 |
| Estrella | Ashton | 88.00 |
| Fernandez | Carmela | 99.05 |
| Benitez | Sally | 81.20 |
| Abanilla | Joseph | 79.35 |

Comment: What do you mean "Does anyone know how to sort a column from a text file"? You need to collect all lines and aggregate them into a data structure for exmaple `struct Node { string firstname; stirng secondname; float grade; }` and then after create a container of such you may call a sort algorithm by name, second name or grade.

Comment: First you need to read each line and split it into first name, last name and grade

Comment: You are not sorting the text file according to last name. You are sorting complete lines, ignoring their internal structure. In order to sort by some element of the internal structure, be it last name, first name, or grade, you need to be able to extract just that element from the input. How you should do that depends on how much of C++ you have already learned, and on how exactly the imp[ut file is formatted. I know neither of these parameters, but here are several keywords for the future search: `struct`, `std::string:substr`, `std::stringstream`, `>>`.

Comment: i have it seperated already but how can i store it in array?  sortByFirst.open("student-file.txt");

 while(getline(sortByFirst, sortedFirst)) 
 {
     istringstream iss(sortedFirst); 
     iss >> col1 >> col2 >> col3; 
     
  cout << "\t" << col2 << endl;

 }

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have followed your advice to split the columns but then I don't know how can I sort the last name and grade accordingly with the first name. I hope you might give me an idea? thank you

Comment: It will not work this way. You need to store the entire student information, and move the entire student information to the new position in the array. Not just the column you compare. I suggest to represent the student information as a *struct*, not as a string. Then you can compare just one element of the struct, but move and print the entire struct.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort things out and here's what I got and same for the other columns. Though it has some flaw, like the header is included in the sorting process. Here's my code:

```
void sortLast() {
    studentRecord records[20];
    string lastname, firstname, grade, key;
    
    ifstream ifs("student-file.txt");
    
    if(ifs.fail()) {
        cout << "Error opening student records file." <<endl;
        exit(1);
     }
     
    int i = 0;
    while(! ifs.eof()){
        ifs >> lastname >> firstname >> grade;
        records[i].lastname = lastname;
        records[i].firstname = firstname;
        records[i].grade = grade;
        i++;
    }  
    
    cout << "\n\n\tSORTED BY LAST NAME =================\n\n";
    for(int i=0;i<19;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<19-1;j++) {
            if(records[j].lastname>records[j+1].lastname) {
                t=records[j];
                records[j]=records[j+1];
                records[j+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int k = 0; k < 19; k++) {
        cout << "\n\t";
        cout.width(15); cout << left << records[k].lastname;
        cout.width(15); cout << left << records[k].firstname << left << records[k].grade << endl;
    }
    
    ifs.close();
}
```